# Is there a way to do this with a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I would like to do this with a for loop.
My code is:

```
PC1 = dfA.iloc[0:23]
PC2 = dfA.iloc[23:46]
PC3 = dfA.iloc[46:69]
PC4 = dfA.iloc[69:92]
PC5 = dfA.iloc[92:115]
PC6 = dfA.iloc[115:138]
PC7 = dfA.iloc[138:161]
PC8 = dfA.iloc[161:184]
PC9 = dfA.iloc[184:207]
PC10 = dfA.iloc[207:230]
PC11 = dfA.iloc[230:253]
PC12 = dfA.iloc[253:276]
PC13 = dfA.iloc[276:299]
PC14 = dfA.iloc[299:322]
PC15 = dfA.iloc[322:345]
PC16 = dfA.iloc[345:368]
PC17 = dfA.iloc[368:391]
```

I tried using a for loop for the numbers in the brackets.

```
for x in range(0,391,23):
    y = x + 23
    PC[i] = dfA.iloc[x:y]
```

But I have not found a way that the datasets will be created as in the code above, with `i` in `range(17)`.

Comment: Your starting code uses steps of 23, but your proposed loop uses steps of 28. Is that intentional? Which do you really want?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, steps of 23 is what i really want.

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks for commenting, I do not think that dictionaries will solve my problem as I need dataframes as the final result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you how to get the value of `i` that you need, given the current value of `x`? What actually is the difficulty? (Hint: list indices start at 0.)

Comment: "I need dataframes as the final result." How does `PC` relate to the intended final result? What will the value of `PC` be before the loop?

Comment: Don't use a dictionary, use a list. Then `PC[16]` (list element) will be the same as `PC17` (variable).

Comment: @Alk12 "I need dataframes as the final result" -- Yeah, of course. We're saying, put the dataframes in a container (list or dict), instead of separate variables.